# Group data for XML data adapter

Tags: xml, jasper-reports

I need some help with JasperReports, Im trying to create a report from an XML file as the data adapter, the list of elements I have looks like this:

Level: Level 6 to 5
 -Speciality: No Speciality
Level: Level 5 to 4
 -Speciality: No Speciality
Level: level-test-first
 -Speciality: Speciality Test-t
 -Speciality: Speciality Test-t2

I want to print it like that too, but in the report, only the first level is printed with the first speciality of each level, something like this:

Level: Level 6 to 5
 -Speciality: No Speciality
 -Speciality: No Speciality
 -Speciality: Speciality Test-t

Im starting to wonder if is even possible to use groups with an XML Data Adapter, since all the examples I've found so far are using SQL Data Adapter

Here is the XML whit the data:

```
<person>
<id>11111</id>
<employeeNumber>12887</employeeNumber>
<name>NAME EXAMPLE </name>
<location>3333</location>
<plan>
    <planId>68</planId>
    <planName>Plan Test</planName>
    <plant/>
    <levels>
        <level>
            <item>
            <description>Level 6 to 5</description>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>Level 6 to 5</name>
            </item>
            <specialities>
                <speciality>
                    <item>
                        <id>0</id>
                        <name>No Speciality</name>
                    </item>
                    <courses/>
                </speciality>
            </specialities>
        </level>
        <level>
            <item>
                <description>Level 5 to 4</description>
                <id>20</id>
                <name>Level 5 to 4</name>
            </item>
            <specialities>
                <speciality>
                    <item>
                        <id>0</id>
                        <name>No Speciality</name>
                    </item>
                    <courses/>
                </speciality>
            </specialities>
        </level>
        <level>
            <item>
                <description>level-test-first</description>
                <id>19</id>
                <name>level-test-first</name>
            </item>
            <specialities>
                <speciality>
                    <item>
                        <description>Speciality Test-t</description>
                        <id>9</id>
                        <name>Speciality Test-t</name>
                    </item>
                </speciality>
                <speciality>
                    <item>
                        <description>Speciality Test-t2</description>
                        <id>10</id>
                        <name>Speciality Test-t2</name>
                    </item>
                    <courses/>
                </speciality>
            </specialities>
        </level>
    </levels>
</plan>
```

This is my report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="pruebaGrupos" language="groovy" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="f9c990e6-305b-46fe-b9ad-f1c992e1cbb9">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="39"/>
<queryString language="XPath">
    <![CDATA[/person/plan/levels/level]]>
</queryString>
<field name="levels" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/person/plan/levels]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="level" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/person/plan/levels/level]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="item" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/person/plan/levels/level/item]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="id" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/person/plan/levels/level/item/id]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/person/plan/levels/level/item/name]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="item2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[specialities/speciality/item]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="name2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[specialities/speciality/item/name]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<group name="groupLevel">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="50">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="64397dc7-2588-4642-8e52-dc8861242ac4"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
        <band height="50"/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="935a54a5-d57d-4f6c-8dfb-93a0ec95ad01"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Speciality Name]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="0b37e00b-b798-4795-bb62-f50c752fae59"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
```

Can someone tell me if Im doing something wrong?, thanks in advance.

Comment: I've found the solution, you can only group one element, for another one you must use a sub report, the XPath should be the path of the parent element from which you want to start the group.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer, not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it worked for me:

For the main report, the XPath should be the path of the parameter you want to use as the group element, following the described scenario, should be something like:

```
<queryString language="XPath"> 
    <![CDATA[/person/plan/levels/level]]> 
</queryString>
```

Then you create a sub report in the details band, the sub report should use a Data source expresion where you use the Path of the element of the second group, something like:

```
<detail>
    <band height="18" splitType="Stretch">
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="572" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="64769eb9-baec-4995-a139-3a5f102f4764"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/level/specialities/speciality")]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subReport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Now you fill the sub report where, if you want to group more elements on it, you should start the XPath in the element you want to group, like in the main report, this should work if you want to create a third group too, you just need to create a sub report and repeat the process.

I hope this help someone, I can expand the explication if needed, just ask.